# Does Mesos Master and Mesos agent require root access?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

Does Mesos Master and Mesos agent require root access? what is the default permission level for Mesos master and Mesos agent? can they run with non-root access?

Answer (score 1):

When I try to start my mesos cluster without root access, I got the error in the mesos slave:

```
Log file created at: 2018/02/17 06:57:48
Running on machine: ubuntu
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
E0217 06:57:48.811517 46316 main.cpp:468] EXIT with status 1: Failed to initialize systemd: Failed to create systemd slice ‘mesos_executors.slice’: Failed to write systemd slice `/run/systemd/system/mesos_executors.slice`: Failed to open file ‘/run/systemd/system/mesos_executors.slice’: Permission denied
```

My mesos cluster consists of three nodes, all the slave host got this error. So I started my mesos cluster with root access in mesos master. It worked.

Comment: I think it depends on the version you are using?

Comment: Perhaps, Best to try it in your own environment.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to run `mesos-agent` with `--no-systemd_enable_support` if you don't want to provide it root access and you are okay without the provided systemd support.

Answer (score 0):

No,
Mesos Master and Mesos agent doesn't need root access.Yes they can run with non-root acess

Comment: Are you sure? I got different answers from different community members.

Comment: Obviously, you need root access to build Apache Mesos. But once you have it just '.tar' it and 'untar' it on the other users. I have set-up 4 node cluster in mesos. I am not sure whether all functionalities of Mesos would work but was able to run Spark applications on it.